# Populating Href With URL from Previous Page?

Tags: url

I'm basically trying to create a button that will take the users back to a search results page of a directory.  Is there any way to populate `href` with the url of the previous page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few add-ons that allow you to do this without having to rely on PHP or Javascript.

[**Mo Variables**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables):

You would want to have `<a href="{last_page_visited}">Back to Search Results</a>` or you could do `<a href="{one_page_visited}">Back to Search Results</a>` the nice thing about Mo Variables is that it allows you to grab up to 5 pages of history from the session.

[**URL Helper**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper):

With URL Helper you would want to use the following `<a href="{referrer}">Back to Search Results</a>`

They both offer similar functionality with each having something that other does not so evaluate them both and see which one suits your needs the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable PHP this will output the previous URL. But HTTP_REFERER can be modified by the users browser.

`<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>`

Answer (score 2):

I extended a bit on Justin's submission, checking to ensure the reference was from within my own site. Eg. I didn't want to send people back to the Google search results page.

```
{exp:ce_str:ing allow_eecode="yes|yes" php}
    <?php 
        $referrer = '{referrer}'; // using extension url_helper (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper)
        $base_url = '{global:base_url}'; // site base path

        if (strpos($referrer, $base_url) === 0) { // check if they start the same
            echo '<a href="{referrer}">Go back</a>'; // add back link to page within site
        }
    ?>
{/exp:ce_str:ing}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could off course also do a href="javascript:history.back();"